# how to text align span/labels text end point should be same vertically?

Tags: css, text, alignment

I want to end all the text/labels at the same point (right-end), the endpoint should match vertically in CSS for different -span labels?

how can I manage through CSS?

[image]

all the text should end at the right line as per the attached image

```
example : https://jsfiddle.net/ths4kdmx/
```

similar like above example-but here text aligned to the right end of the screen, but I want to end in the middle of the screen where all the labels should end vertically

Comment: text-align:right? I'm not sure what the problem is. Perhaps you should show your HTML.

Comment: What code you are using? Using any bootstrap? You need to provide the details here.

Comment: all the text should end at the right line as per the attached image

Comment: Add a relevant code snippet. This question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

Make your span of same width and then apply `text-align: right` property on that.